# For a bounded and integrable function $|g| \leq |R|$ we have that $\left|\int_{x_0}^x g(x)\ \mathrm{d}x \right| \leq R |b-a|$

Tags: real-analysis

As stated in the title the trouble arises from the following.

For a bounded and integrable function, $g: I \to \mathbb{R}$, $|g| \leq |R|$ we have that $\left|\int_{x_0}^x g(x)\ \mathrm{d}x \right| \leq R |b-a|$. Now, because we are looking at not only $x>x_0$ but also $x<x_0$ with the convention that if $x<x_0$ the integral becomes

$$
\int_{x_0}^x g(x)\ \mathrm{d}x = -\int_{x}^{x_0} g(x)\ \mathrm{d}x
$$

I start to have trouble proving this. Could anyone assist? (Please keep this in the context of the Riemann integral only, thank you.)

Comment: What is the exact source of difficulty? Is the issue the interchange of the lower and upper limits of integration?

Comment: Essentially yes. I just constantly seem to screw up my inequalities when I attempt to show this. Intuitively, the idea makes sense to me that if I know that function has some value that it is bounded by, then the integral cannot exceed the "box" formed by the interval length times that value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The definite integral is defined in terms of Riemann sums as

$$\int_a^b f(x) dx = \lim_{N \to \infty} \sum_{n=1}^{N} f(\bar x_i)\Delta x$$

where $\bar x_i$ is any point in the $i$th partition and $\Delta x = \frac{b-a}{N}$.

Then,

$$\int_b^a f(x) dx = \lim_{N \to \infty} \sum_{n=1}^{N} f(\bar x_i')\Delta x'$$

where $\bar x_i'$ is any point in the $i$th partition and $\Delta x' = \frac{a-b}{N}$.

Inasmuch as $\Delta x = - \Delta x'$, we have

$$\int_a^b f(x) dx = -\int_b^a f(x) dx $$

Taking absolute values of both sides of the last equation reveals that

$$\left| \int_a^b f(x) dx\right| = \left|-\int_b^a f(x) dx \right|=\left|\int_b^a f(x) dx \right|$$